# Piwik: PHP upgrade broke Piwik

Tags: php, debian, analytics, matomo

I have upgraded PHP from 5.3.7 to 5.4.4 on my Debian 6 (Squeeze) system. After this upgrade Piwik stopped working. The following error occurs:

`The string to escape is not a valid UTF-8 string in "@CoreHome/getDefaultIndexView.twig".`

I tried Googling, but could not get any solution. Anyone knows how to fix this error?

Thanks,
Anji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have issues with the update process, download Piwik manually and replace it with your installed system.

For security reasons, take a backup from your database and your config file.

Comment: After the update, I re-installed Piwik (actually several times) but no luck :(

Comment: Please check the default charsets. For example in Apache: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` (/etc/apache2/conf.d/charset), PHP: `default_charset = "UTF-8"` (/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini).